# Should I trash my router if it still runs OpenSSL 0.9.8p and OpenVPN 2.2.2 in 2017?

Tags: tls, privacy, openssl, router, openvpn

I have the [Easybox 904 xDSL](https://www.vodafone.de/business/hilfe-support/support-firmware-easybox-904-xdsl.html) router from Vodafone (Germany) running the latest firmware *03.17.01.17*.

I wanted to upgrade the firmware but found out that the latest version is from 2015 - no updates since then. There's a list of all [open source software used in this router](https://www.vodafone.de/downloadarea/EasyBox_904xDSL_Open_Source_Software_AT904X-03.17.01.16.pdf), including:

- OpenSSL 0.9.8p
- OpenVPN 2.2.2
- linux kernel modules, V2.6.32

What I actually want to accomplish is to gain access to a Synology DS916+ running the latest OS, having *letsencrypt* certificates and lots of security configured:

- access CloudStation and FileStation using dynamic DNS and port-forwarding
- access Gitlab by using a VPN-connection to my network

*Is it still secure using this router or should I get a new one?*

Comment: If its an ISP provided router try complaining to your ISP that its not fit for purpose. They may issue a new one.

Comment: @Hector Thought about that as well. Unfortunately I got this router from the ISP but not as a rental. Also it is still their best router as far as I can guess. So I doubt that they will exchange it or that I will get any newer/better product from them.

Comment: Disable everything you can on this router and get upgradable router with DD-WRT. These usually don't have DSL support so you can keep your existing DSL router.

Comment: @lampshade - Rental? Such a weird concept to me! In the UK you are issued a router (which theoretically remains their property but its unheard of for them to ask for them back). I'd still say its worth asking for an upgrade - worst case they say no. They still issue these things? I'd launch a complaint and assuming they do nothing about it contact a prominent security researcher ideally from within your country - a tweet from someone well known could be enough to kick them into action.

Comment: Maybe send a tweet to the [CCC](https://twitter.com/chaosupdates) or [netzpolitik.org](https://twitter.com/netzpolitik) and see if they can nudge Vodafone into issuing some routers with newer software.

Comment: Linux 2.6.32 was a long-term kernel version; it appears that the last version released is 2.6.32.71 on 2016-03-12 [see](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/longterm/v2.6.32/), and the original release was 2009-12-03 [see](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/). Far from great, but not necessarily horrible in late 2017, especially if you value stability over having the latest gizmos. Distributions may have provided updates for even longer that didn't make it into the upstream tree. Of course, by now it's late 2018...

Answer (score -1):

You may disable all the features you don't want to use on your router. You can enable SSH only when needed and keep it disabled at all other times. Port forwarding and connection over VPN to your local devices is very good approach. Also make sure there is no way to connect to your router from the internet - allow access only from your local network and always via SSL if possible. Use UPS to power your router and if you have to REBOOT it do it offline, then connect the internet wire once fully rebooted. Routers tend to be vulnerable during the boot sequence, typical attack might be to force the user to reboot the router and then attack it.

Comment: please do not add signatures to your posts